# My navigation menu disappears when the window resizes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is my [wordpress site](http://www.smart-charge.no).

When the window gets smaller, the navigation menu disappears and the logo gets bigger.

What can I do to keep the logo and a fixed size in relation to the window size and also make sure the navigation menu doesnt disappear ?

I am pretty new to wordpress and css etc. So it would be useful if someone gave me some tips.

I think I am supposed to use an `@media query`, thats about all I know. WP is a little bit confusing to use.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please read this article and try to improve your question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

because your wp theme seem to use the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), when your window gets smaller than 992px 
these code  work：

```
@media (max-width: 992px)
#nav-main ul.sf-menu {
 display: none; 
}
```

so you can find the bootstrap.css and delete these code up there.

Then you will got this:

[image]

Comment: THanks. I cant seem to find any file named "bootstrap.css".

Comment: @user3702037 Ok, then you can add it to your own `.css` file. like `@media (max-width: 992px){
#nav-main ul.sf-menu {
 display: block !important; 
}}`

Comment: Also you may find the `bootstrap.css` here `http://smart-charge-no.mrbazaari.com/wp-content/themes/virtue/assets/css/bootstrap.css?ver=204`